#  instead of numbers when parsing (scraping)

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, web-scraping

Good afternoon.
When trying to parse a similar page https://www.dongchedi.com/usedcar/12441930
Instead of price numbers, the page code displays 

[item image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmXIY.png)

```
<p class="jsx-1166026127 tw-text-color-red-500 tw-font-semibold tw-text-20 xl:tw-text-24 tw-leading-32 xl:tw-leading-36 font-zmQZz5CrbrbHudeQ">.</p>
```

When you try to copy a number from the side,  is copied instead of numbers.

Any ideas why this happens? And how to get the price.

I assume the price is generated by a java script and is substituted at some point. But these numbers are nowhere in the page code. json contains values ​​not related to price.

Comment: the page at the end contains a block of JavaScript (size 105564 bytes) that looks like some data structure (no logic), as if the page needs to be build using this data, but the original `wget` already contains a lot of `div` tags with content.

Comment: Thank you. I saw this block, it looks like it is needed for uploading photos. I'm wondering if this crooked logic in writing the page is on purpose...

Comment: why would they put stuff in the HTML to upload photos for customers of the site, they have so many minified JavaScript logic in many `chunk` files that it is unknown to find out what they do unless you have loads of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page is being quite sneaky.

That `p` element has the `font-zmQZz5CrbrbHudeQ` class. Finding where this class is defined (inline), we get the following CSS:

```css
.font-zmQZz5CrbrbHudeQ {
  font-family:zmQZz5CrbrbHudeQ;
}
```

It looks like the font is displaying these strange glyphs as numbers.

Here's the correspondence:

| Character | Unicode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | U+E53D |
| 2 | U+E3F0 |
| 3 | U+E422 |
| 4 | U+E42C |
| 5 | U+E49C |
| 6 | U+E42B |
| 7 | U+E4FE |
| 8 | U+E548 |
| 9 | U+E4C8 |
| 0 | U+E453 |
| 万 | U+E45F |

You can use the above table to convert the unreadable characters into normal numeric digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wonder for what purpose the Chinese do this... I suppose it’s to protect against scraping. Please tell me how you got the decoding table?

Comment: I went to the page that had all the cars listed, and picked out cars so I had all the digits. I then compared the characters in the HTML to the displayed text manually, since there are only 10. Hope this helps :)

Comment: After your first answer, I did exactly the same :-) I think the Chinese can dynamically change decryption tables... and the scraping script can break at any time :-(